# C# insert into FK table asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How can I insert into foreign key table in asp.net? I just have a problem with inserting the foreign attribute.. i need to insert into employee table with FK attribute which is the department id. 
I have problem with this query:

```
string insCmd = "insert into emp(id, name, phone, email) values (@id, @name, @phone, @email); select identity_scope;";
```

i didn't get any errors but the insertion does not occur. thanks..

Comment: Can you include the code for what you have tried and include what errors you are getting?

Comment: i cant post long comment so i edit my question

Comment: Without seeing your table structure, the data you're passing in and a whole load of other possible problems, it will be impossible for anybody here to help you. If you're not getting an error, then I would suggest you look carefully where it's inserting into, for example if you have multiple databases

Comment: how are you trying to execute the query? also, which is the FK column? do you want to add a value for that column or leave it null?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see two problems with your insert statement.

1. It's `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, not `identity_scope`.
2. You are trying to insert to the `id` column, which is not allowed if
   this is defined as an IDENTITY column.

Change your statement to this:

```
string insCmd = "insert into emp(name, phone, email) values (@name, @phone, @email); select @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
```

Also, you should define `@id` as an Output parameter.

Comment: How can you assert that its `SCOPE_IDENTITY`? you don't know the DB engine behind the scene. Actually the question is so poorly written (even with the recommendation of the commentators) that we shouldn't put efforts to answer unless the OP gives more details.

Comment: A fair point, call it an educated guess. A quick search of Google for `identity_scope` returns no direct hits and only SQL Server near hits. I was fairly certain only SQL Server and Sybase refer to a column as IDENTITY, and Sybase seemed like a stretch given the question is tagged ASP.NET.

Comment: you are probably right about your guess. It was actually a pretext to criticize the quality of the question.